# Facing issue while using MySQL RELEASE_LOCK function

Tags: mysql, hibernate, dropwizard

In our microservice, we exposed 2 APIs both of them finally try to read, insert and update the same resource. So to avoid data inconsistency we try to serialize the request by taking lock-on the key (the key is derived from request data and always be the same in both APIs).

code Snippet

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
String lockKey = "key-name";
try {
  // acquire lock  query= SELECT GET_LOCK(lockKey, 5000)
  hibernateMysqlLock.acquireLockOrException(lockKey, session);
  someService.execute(someObject);
} finally {

  // releasing lock  query= SELECT RELEASE_LOCK(lockKey)
  hibernateMysqlLock.release(lockKey, session);
  session.close();
}
```

Most of the time `SELECT RELEASE_LOCK(lockKey)` is not releasing lock and return 0 and 0 means   ***the lock was not established by this thread (in which case the lock is not released)***, (according to doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html#function_release-lock)

Need help in fixing issue and also suggest better approach if possible

Tech Stack: dropwizard (with hibernate) and MySQL (as datastore)